# String routines

Tags: strings, assembly, x86

These are a few string routines (just the `mem*` ones). I've tried to optimize them the best I can without having them be too big, but I'm unsure if I've done a good job.

I'd prefer size over speed unless it's just a few bytes, in which case that would be fine. I would also prefer not to sacrifice simplicity for speed.

`memchr.S` ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524415/is-cmovcc-considered-a-branching-instruction)):

```
.globl memchr
memchr:
        mov %rdx, %rcx
        movzbl %sil, %eax
        repne scasb
        lea -1(%rdi), %rax
        test %rcx, %rcx
        cmove %rcx, %rax
        ret
```

`memcmp.S`:

```
.globl memcmp
memcmp:
        mov %rdx, %rcx
        repe cmpsb
        movzbl -1(%rdi), %eax
        movzbl -1(%rsi), %edx
        sub %edx, %eax
        ret
```

`memcpy.S`:

```
.globl memcpy
memcpy:
        mov %rdx, %rcx
        mov %rdi, %rax
        rep movsb
        ret
```

`memmove.S`:

```
.globl memmove
memmove:
        mov %rdx, %rcx
        mov %rdi, %rax
        cmp %rdi, %rsi
        jge 0f
        dec %rdx
        add %rdx, %rdi
        add %rdx, %rsi
        std
0:      rep movsb
        cld
        ret
```

`memrchr.S`:

```
.globl memrchr
memrchr:
        mov %rdx, %rcx
        add %rdx, %rdi
        movzbl %sil, %eax
        std
        repne scasb
        cld
        lea 1(%rdi), %rax
        test %rcx, %rcx
        cmove %rcx, %rax
        ret
```

`memset.S`:

```
.globl memset
memset:
        mov %rdx, %rcx
        mov %rdi, %rdx
        movzbl %sil, %eax
        rep stosb
        mov %rdx, %rax
        ret
```

As usual for Stack Exchange sites, this code is released under CC/by-sa 3.0, but any future changes can be accessed [here](https://github.com/JL2210/minilibc/tree/master/arch/x86_64/src/string/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks straight-forward and really optimized for size and simplicity.

There's a small detail that I would change, though: replace `cmove` with `cmovz`, to make the code more expressive. It's not that "being equal" would be of any interest here, it's the zeroness of `%ecx` that is interesting.

I like the omitted second `jmp` in memmove. It's obvious after thinking a few seconds about it.

[According to this quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26104615) it's ok to rely on the direction flag being always cleared.

I still suggest to write a few unit tests to be on the safe side.

Comment: See my answer for a bug that I found on my own (found by writing unit tests).

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug in your code if `memchr` finds `%sil` in the last byte of `%rdi`; if `%rcx` tests to be zero and yet the byte has been found, it will incorrectly return zero.

To fix that, do something like this:

```
.globl memchr
memchr:
        mov %rdx, %rcx
        movzbl %sil, %eax
        repne scasb
        sete %cl
        lea -1(%rdi), %rax
        test %cl, %cl
        cmovz %rcx, %rax
        ret
```

The same applies to `memrchr`.

Answer (score 1):

In memmove you have the following:

```
        cmp %rdi, %rsi
        jge 0f
```

(`cmp rsi, rdi` in Intel syntax I believe.) For rsi = 8000_0000_0000_0000h and rdi = 7FFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFFh (we want to jump to make a forward move here) the signed-comparison conditional branch "jump if greater or equal" evaluates rsi as being "less than" rdi (rsi being a negative number in 64-bit two's complement while rdi is positive), so it doesn't jump and will make a backwards move. This is incorrect. You should use the equivalent unsigned branch "jump if above or equal", `jae` instead.

Comment: Isn't this only an issue when a userspace address and kernelspace address are mixed?

Comment: How likely is this in reality, though? The least you could expect is a segfault.

Comment: It may not be an issue depending on the operating system / address-space layout. However, if it does happen, then a wrong move direction (if the buffers are actually overlapping) will result in silently corrupting the destination buffer.

Comment: This won't ever happen because addresses are only actually used up to 48 bits, much less than `0x8000000000000000`.